# Moving to SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server

We currently use SharePoint 2013. This was installed about 3 years ago by a vendor. I think it may have been their first install because we have seen several things that were not set up correctly. We have had some weird issues, anomalies and things not working correctly  from time to time. So my thought is rather than upgrade to 2016, we stand up a new farm on new servers for 2016. What are the pro's and con's?  What does this involve? Are there any third party tools that we could use to transfer content from  SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016?

Please be as detailed as possible.
Thanks

Comment: How much content do you have in your environment?  How many web apps?  How big is the farm, in general?

Answer (score 2):

I would do this way.

- Build a new SharePoint 2016 Farm.
- Create and configure the Services Applications( I.e Search, UPA, MMS etc)
- Create and configure the Web Applications.

Now we have two choices.

1. Backup the Content Database from 2013 and restore it 2016 sql server. Now upgrade / attache to SharePoint 2016. But as you said you have alot issue in 2013, this will give you bad migration experience. You have to do a lot of work, clean the data in 2013 then after migration also make sure no orphan/ bad data come over.
2. Or you can use the third party tool which will help to migrate the content, it will be clean, end result will SharePoint 2016 fresh install. I would prefer this method. You can try sharegate( cheap) or Metalogix migration tools as they offer trial version as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a new 2016 server. For install you can use auto install scripts

https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/

Once this is done. You can copy the 2013 content databases and attach it to 2016. Next step is to upgrade those databases into 2016 format.

Below link is for 2013, but the steps remains same for 2016

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with above suggestions. In addition to above few more tools are their, you could try like:

[Dell Migration for SharePoint](http://software.dell.com/products/migration-suite-for-sharepoint/)

[Lepide Migrator for SharePoint](http://www.lepide.com/lepidemigratordocuments/sharepoint-to-office-365-migration.html)

[AvePoint DocAve Migrators](http://www.avepoint.com/office-365-and-sharepoint-migration/)

Here is a similar [thread](http://sharepoint-community.net/forum/topics/moving-to-sharepoint-2016) with suggested solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, your best bet is a 3rd party migration tool. You might want to check out this guide wrote by one of them: http://en.share-gate.com/blog/10-tips-sharepoint-2016-migration